# A batch-normalization error in the epsilon of tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

We found that the implementation of tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization does not conform to its mathematical model. The cause of the problem may come from its epsilon or variance parameter.  The occurrence of error is specifically divided into four steps:

(1)Initialize a BN operator (i.e. source_model), randomly input an input (i.e. data), and get an output (i.e. source_result);

(2)Randomly generate a perturbation (i.e. delta). Add the variance of source_model to delta, and subtract delta from epsilon to get a new BN operator (i.e. follow_model);

(3)Input data to follow_model and get a follow_result;

(4)Calculate the distance between source_result and follow_result. Theoretically, it should be small or even 0, in practice it can get a result greater than 1

```
# from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Input
# from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, clone_model
from tensorflow._api.v1.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Input
from tensorflow._api.v1.keras.models import Model, clone_model

import os
import re
import numpy as np

def SourceModel(shape):
    x = Input(shape=shape[1:])
    y = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
    return Model(x, y)

def FollowModel_1(source_model):
    follow_model = clone_model(source_model)
    # read weights
    weights = source_model.get_weights()
    weights_names = [weight.name for layer in source_model.layers for weight in layer.weights]
    variance_idx = FindWeightsIdx("variance", weights_names)

    # mutation operator
    # delta = np.random.uniform(-1e-3, 1e-3, 1)[0]
    follow_model.layers[1].epsilon += delta     # mutation epsilon
    weights[variance_idx] -= delta
    follow_model.set_weights(weights)

    return follow_model

def FindWeightsIdx(name, weights_names):
    # find layer index by name
    for idx, names in enumerate(weights_names):
        if re.search(name, names):
            return idx
    return -1

os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"

shape = (10, 32, 32, 3)
data = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, shape)
delta = -1

source_model = SourceModel(shape)
follow_model = FollowModel_1(source_model)

source_result = source_model.predict(data)
follow_result = follow_model.predict(data)
dis = np.sum(abs(source_result-follow_result))

print("delta:", delta, "; dis:", dis)
```

No matter how big delta is, dis should be smaller, but it is not. This shows that there may be a bug in the batch-norm operator of tensorflow. This problem occurs in both tf1.x and tf2.x

```
delta: -1 ; dis: 4497.482
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this is a bug so much as undocumented behavior.

I noticed that, with your code, I did not get any difference for `delta > 0`, or in fact any `delta > -0.001` -- the default epsilon is `0.001`, so using a larger delta means we still have `epsilon > 0`. Any larger negative delta (in particular -1 as in your example) will cause `epsilon < 0`.

Is `epsilon < 0` a problem? Yes, because you need to prevent dividing by 0 when dividing by the variance. Variance is always > 0, so subtracting something here might cause a divide by 0. The more pertinent issue is that epsilon is added to the variance, and then the square root is taken to get the standard deviation, which would crash in case `variance + epsilon` is < 0, which can happen for small variance and `epsilon < 0`.

My hunch was that somewhere in the code, they do something like taking `abs(epsilon)` to prevent such issues. However, I couldn't find anything in [the layer implementation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e6784e4302c7b8cd116b74a784f4b78d60e83c26/keras/layers/normalization/batch_normalization.py#L37) and also not in [the op that is used by the layer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.11.0/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L1526-L1594).

However, BN by default uses a "fused" implementation which is faster. [This is here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.11.0/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L1599). And there we see these lines:

```
# Set a minimum epsilon to 1.001e-5, which is a requirement by CUDNN to
# prevent exception (see cudnn.h).
min_epsilon = 1.001e-5
epsilon = epsilon if epsilon > min_epsilon else min_epsilon
```

So indeed, epsilon is always positive. The only thing I don't understand is, you can pass `fused=False` to the BN constructor, and this should use the more basic implementation, where I couldn't find anything that modifies epsilon. But when I tested it, the issue still remained. Not sure what the problem is...

tl;dr: You have `epsilon < 0`. Don't do that, it's bad.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know that epsilon should be positive under normal conditions. But a reliable program should check the legality of the input parameters, or remind us that it is wrong in time. Outputting an abnormal value makes it difficult to locate the source of the error. We also tested other deep learning libraries, using the same settings, the output of Pytorch is normal, and MXNet will output error messages. Therefore, we think that Tensorflow should add the code for checking the validity of epsilon.

Comment: I agree, silent behavior like this is bad. However there is nothing we can do about it here. Maybe you want to open an issue on the Tensorflow/Keras Github.